# Height of 2-3-4 tree

Tags: java, tree, height

I have a working snippet to use for a regular tree comprising nodes. Now I just need to fiddle with it to work for 2-3-4 trees, which should be easier, since each path is the same distance, since it's balanced, right?

Methods I have at my disposal include `getNextChild()`, `split()`, and of course `insert()`.

```
public int height() {
    return (height(root));
}

private int height(TNode localRoot) {
    if(localRoot == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
       //Find each sides depth
       int lDepth = height(localRoot.leftChild);
       int rDepth = height(localRoot.rightChild);

       //Use the larger of the two
       return (Math.max(lDepth, rDepth) + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could just get rid of left and right depth and use one line getting next child?

Comment: @John I think that breaks the concept of a tree

Comment: True, but concerning just finding and returning the height it shouldn't matter which path I take? If they all return the same?

Comment: @John I believe that would be correct, unless of course you improperly implement the 2-4 tree :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo: External nodes in B-Trees have by definition always the same height.

Comment: @poke I am not questioning whether or not B-trees have this property, I am questioning if he implemented the data structure properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int height ()
{
    TNode cur = root;
    int depth = -1;

    while ( cur != null )
    {
        cur = cur.getChild( 0 );
        depth++;
    }

    return depth;
}
```

Comment: should add a check to make sure root is not null

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Good catch, updated to iterate differently (and return a height of -1 when the tree is empty).

Comment: it should probably be: `return ++depth;`  so you don't return `0` if it is depth of `1`

Comment: A tree has a height of 0 when there is just the root.

Comment: This is either giving me an array out of bounds, or with some slight adjustments keeps returning me 2..

I have getChild which takes in intChildNum
Or getParent which is parameterless..

Comment: Oh well, you didn't tell us how to access the childs of a node before; have adjusted my answer, I guess it should work like that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's balanced, you should just be able to recurse down one side of the tree to determine the height.